# How to close window without triggering 'window.onunload'?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an external program that opens an **.hta** file which contains some JavaScript:

```
function getLUTKey(key) {
  // Write txt file to user's file system
  var fso, fh;
  fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  fh = fso.CreateTextFile("PartID.txt", true);

  fh.Write(key);
  fh.close();
  self.close();
}
```

The idea is that the window contains a number of links for different parts which, when clicked, will write their respective "Part ID" to a file using the above js function. The previously-mentioned external program then waits in the background for this file to be created, then uses the file's contents.

However, in order to prevent the user from exiting without selecting a part - 
therefore never creating a file and leaving the external program to loop until a timeout triggers - I've added the following code:

```
window.onunload = function(){ getLUTKey('cancel') };
```

This creates another problem. When `getLUTKey()` is run with a valid ID, and it closes the window, the `window.unload` the code runs immediately after, overwriting whatever the ID in the file was with "cancel". My question is this:

**Is there a way to close a window in javascript without triggering `window.unload`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's way easier for you to manage the state of your app. For example you can simply remove the handler of window closing after you're done with the function.

```
function getLUTKey(key){
// Write txt file to user's file system 
var fso, fh;
fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
fh = fso.CreateTextFile('PartID.txt', true);     
fh.Write(key);          
fh.close();
window.onunload = null;
self.close();
}
```